# Debugging does not stop when a windows is closed

Tags: c#, debugging

I have the exact same problem as [this post to Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d62cab52-00d3-4bbf-9a2e-929b26027f5e/debugging-not-stop-when-close-form?forum=wpf). 
In my case, I have never had this problem when building my own windows forms programs. But I got some code for a book that although works fine does not terminate when I click the X in the windows form. The form dissapears but the process is still running.

It is a simple form with simple controls and the required

```
protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
{
    if( disposing )
    {
        if (components != null) 
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
    }
    base.Dispose( disposing );
}


[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

In the link I posted, there is a "solution" to this, but it does not address why this could be happening which is the important point here.Any thoughts or experience with this?

Comment: Please can you provide an [mcve]? It sounds like you're running some code on another thread, and not terminating it when/before you close the form.

Comment: Generally the debugger continuing to run means that, even though the main window closed, the application did not stop. There's a ton of possible reasons for this, and without a better look at your code it's impossible to say which is the cause.

Comment: Possibly a background thread or task.

Comment: Threads in Windows can be marked as a "background thread" or "foreground thread" - when all foreground threads end then the process will be terminated even if other _background_ threads are running ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads ) - so this means you have a foreground thread still running, even if the process doesn't display a window. Use your debugger's Pause/Break button then look at the Threads list to see what threads are still running and what their stack traces are.

Comment: @Dai Thanks. Although I am not sure how to correctly see the threads I found out that the author is using a worker thread for some video library he is using, so I suppose that is what makes the application not terminate.

Comment: What kind of program is this? Whose `Dispose()` method is being overridden here?